# How to denote at least one repetition in EBNF?

Tags: repeat, ebnf

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

The above article mentions that curly braces denote repetition of arbitrary times (incl. zero), while square brackets denote at most one repetition.

What I want however, is at least one repetition - that is, a terminal or a nonterminal must appear at least once.

Well I can describe it like that:

```
production = nonterminal, { nonterminal };
```

But I thought the point of EBNF over BNF was to avoid the need of this kind of "hacks".

The Wikipedia article also mentions:

> EBNF also provides, among other things, the syntax to describe repetitions (of a specified number of times), to exclude some part of a production, and to insert comments in an EBNF grammar.

But does EBNF provide the syntax to describe at least one repetition?

Answer (score 4):

Place a minus (except-symbol) after the final brace.

```
production = { nonterminal }-;
```

ISO/IEC 14977 : 1996(E)

> 5.8 Syntactic-term
>
> When a syntactic-term is a single syntactic-factor it represents any
>   sequence of symbols represented by that syntactic-factor.
>
> When a syntactic-term is a syntactic-factor followed by an
>   except-symbol followed by a syntactic-exception it represents any
>   sequence of symbols that *satisfies both of the conditions:*
>
> a) it is a sequence of symbols represented by the syntactic-factor,
>
> b) it is not a sequence of symbols represented by the
>   syntactic-exception.
>
> As examples the following syntax-rules illustrate the facilities
>   provided by the except-symbol.
>
> letter = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F"
>       | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M"
>       | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T"
>       | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z";
>   vowel = "A" | "E" | "I" | "O" |"U";
>   consonant = letter - vowel;
>   ee = {"A"}-, "E";
>
> Terminal-strings defined by these rules are as follows:
>
> letter:   A B C D E F G H I J etc.
>   vowel:    A E I O U
>   consonant:  B C D F G H J K L M etc.
>   ee:       AE AAE AAAE AAAAE AAAAAE etc.
>
> NOTE — {"A"}- represents a sequence of one or more A’s because it is a
>   syntactic-term with an empty syntactic-exception.

Note that in the second paragraph (emphasis added), *satisfies both of the conditions*. That is, both the *syntactic-factor* and the *syntactic-exception* must be satisfied. The braces still mean repetition. This results in *one or more* to satisfy the syntax, even though the exception is empty.